# Функция glReadPixel считывает разные значения на маке и на компьютере с убунту

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Ниже представленный код по разному работает на разных компах. На компе с убунту делает гифку начиная с нижней левой точки размером  800x800, а на маке начальная точка отрисовки съезжает вниз влево. Почему так происходит?

```
class GLWidget {
  int gifWidth = 800;
  int gifHeight = 800;
  uint8_t image[800 * 800 * 4];
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
/*code*/
    glReadPixels(0, 0, gifWidth, gifHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
}


void GLWidget::saveGif() {
  QDateTime curTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
  QString time = curTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
  QString fileName = time + ".gif";  // Путь к файлу
  int delay = 100;
  GifWriter g;
  GifBegin(&g, fileName.toStdString().c_str(), gifWidth, gifHeight, delay);
  for (int timer = 0; timer <= 5000; timer += delay) {
    GifWriteFrame(&g, image, gifWidth, gifHeight, 1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
  }
  qDebug() << "Gif is ready";
  GifEnd(&g);
}
```

[image: гифка на убунту]

[image: гифка на убунту]

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить картинок: все окно целиком, и две гифки - на маке и на убунте. Область 800x800 целиком влезает в окно?

Comment: Начальная точка может быть в разных местах, например вверху-слева. Как расположение точки, так и ваши съезды необходимо решать через получение высоты viewport'а `glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &viewport)` и дальнейшего расчёта стартовой точки.

Comment: Добавил изображения. Сейчас изучу viewport. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Если в окне картинка нормальная, а в гифке плохая, то дело не в `glViewport`.

Comment: На маке бывает такое, что размер окна считается в "логических" пикселях, а настоящее разрешение в два раза больше (1600х1600?). Покопайте Qt, может там где-то есть геттер для "framebuffer size".

Comment: расширение у glwidgeta фиксированное 800x800, ощущение такое что точка отрисовки 0,0 имеет координаты -400, -400 на маке, на маке отлично отрабатывает вариант glReadPixels(gifWidth / 2, gifHeight / 2 , gifWidth, gifHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);